# how id is generated in back for particular object in jquery.please some one tell me

Tags: javascript

how id is generated in back for particular object in jquery like this

```
function wpPopupPos(objMenu, w)
{
    var pos = $("#"+objMenu.id).offset();

    var wraper = $('#custommenu');
```

m not getting it ,how custommenu id is generated

Comment: `custommenu` is an ID present in a DOM element. Like `<div id="custommenu"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute of an HTML element is unique value to uniquely identify that element. It is defined by the "id" attribute. It is not generated, it is defined by the designer. For id selectors, Jquery uses "#".

var wraper = $('#custommenu'); - This uses "#" as the selector and "custommenu" string which is the id for your div.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be better to give up on this one, as I gave about the same response and he decided to ask an even more confusing question.

Comment: :) Agree. Can't really deduce what he is asking.

Comment: function wpPopupPos(objMenu, w)
{
    var pos = $("#"+objMenu.id).offset();
    var wraper = $('#custommenu');
      var posWraper = wraper.offset();

Comment: here wat happens m not getting it inside above code

Comment: how any integer value comes inside pos and wraper

Comment: The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the document.
.offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left.
<script>
var p = $( "p:last" );
var offset = p.offset();
p.html( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
</script> 
This will return : left: 10, top: 50. The numbers are the cordinates.

Comment: i m not confusing,u don't wanna to answer my question,.help me understanding this code----function wpPopupPos(objMenu, w)
{
    var pos = $("#"+objMenu.id).offset();

    var wraper = $('#custommenu');
  
    var posWraper = wraper.offset();
    var wWraper = wraper.width() - CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_RIGHT_OFFSET_MIN;
    var xTop = pos.top - posWraper.top + CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_TOP_OFFSET;
    var xLeft = pos.left - posWraper.left; 
   
    pos =$(objMenu.id);
    pos.addClass('active');
    if ((xLeft + w) > wWraper)
    xLeft = wWraper - w ;
   // alert(xLeft);
    return {'top': xTop, 'left': xLeft};

Comment: I have modified my answer and tried to explain what is happening with your code. Take a look.

Comment: wat happend? no one is there to clarify my doubts n explain above code

Comment: but till now i didn;t get ur modified answer

Answer (score 0):

The id is *not generated*, you actually define it. If, in your document, you have something like `<div id="custommenu"></div>`, then thats where the id gets defined. An `id` is like naming a child, you simple name it and then call it by that name - how on earth would I otherwise know which child is mine? What child I should face-paint like a tiger?

This is a bad question, by the way. There no explanation and clearly no ressearch done. Please try harder.

Comment: ya that's why m asking we define id as a string like custommenu,but how it takes integer value,as we used this id like     var wraper = $('#custommenu');

Comment: What integer value? Are you asking how jQuery stores objects? Why are you worrying about that? All jQuery does when you do $("#custommenu") is return you an object that gets a lot of stuff jQuery uses to do its job. You are not clear enough in asking your question and I am incredibly unsure of what you are asking because of it.

Answer (score 0):

--- Code-------------

```
function wpPopupPos(objMenu, w) { 
var pos = $("#"+objMenu.id).offset(); 
var wraper = $('#custommenu'); 
var posWraper = wraper.offset(); 
var wWraper = wraper.width() - CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_RIGHT_OFFSET_MIN; 
var xTop = pos.top - posWraper.top + CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_TOP_OFFSET; 
var xLeft = pos.left - posWraper.left; 
pos =$(objMenu.id); 
pos.addClass('active'); 
if ((xLeft + w) > wWraper) xLeft = wWraper - w ; 
// alert(xLeft); 
return {'top': xTop, 'left': xLeft};
```

-------Explanation----------

Because of .offset()

-- pos gets an object with the top and left coordinate of objMenu

-- posWraper gets an object with the top and left coordinates of custommenu

.width() returns the content width

xTop takes the pos and posWraper top values and substracts them. Same is done with left values and stored in xLeft.

Comment: thanks al ot kurenai.Actually m new in Ui part,don;t know even silly question.tha'ts why want to understand this code.my boss has given me work to do proper alignment

Comment: It is fine. Please ask question properly next time. If the code was provided in the beginning there would have been no confusion. :)